# Is Super Meat Boy really harder with a keyboard?

Tags: controllers, keyboard, super-meat-boy

While poking around on Youtube I found many commenters saying "yeah, now try that with a keyboard." The game itself, however, only seems to suggest a controller to keep the "feeling" of the game.

[image]

I played with the keyboard so far, and I'm 10 levels from completing world 5. Sure, my completion rates for worlds 2-5 are below 30% and I only have 11/100 bandages so far – I still do value my sanity – yet I'd rather think it's *me* not being good enough, than thinking I'm bringing artificial difficulty onto myself for not wanting to buy a controller.

The only gripe I have with the controls is that you need to *release* <kbd>Space</kbd> after having gained enough elevation before you can jump again by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> again. I'm not sure using a smaller button, or a different finger, would make this any less frustrating however.

Is Super Meat Boy actually harder to play with a keyboard?

Comment: Keep in mind that while the answers here may explain reasons for the *default* difficulty of one input device versus the other, transitioning from any device to another can actually prove more difficult at first if you have fine-tuned mastery of the first.

Comment: Ive made sure to address that in my answer.

Comment: Thumbs before fingers. Live it.

Comment: I finished all light worlds and something like 70% of dark levels with my keyboard (and couldn't remap the freaking keys), it was fun but painfull physically ^^ and you actually destroy your keyboard... I recently bought a xbox adapter and can't believe how easier/enjoyable it is to play that way

Comment: -1 because the accepted answer is wrong

Comment: @Lohoris then write your own; the current answer is not perfect, but as good as I've got so far.

Comment: @badp: Toto's answer is correct and I upvoted that; comments to Sadly Not's answer explain very clearly why his answer is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Super Meat Boy is easier with a gamepad only if gamepad is the input device you are more at ease with generally speaking, that's all.
A few top players (Breakdown, Joe) play on keyboard and it's pretty obvious it doesn't hinder their skill. I would play SMB using keyboard rather than a gamepad myself if I didn't have an arcade stick, which I prefer to use.
Last but not least: SMB default keyboard layout isn't exactly optimal IIRC, but that is easy to change.

Comment: This answer is accurate.  There is no difference in the inputs between xbox and PC for the game. Meatboy doesn't make use of the analogue features of the xbox controller.  See [this interview with the developer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVpSIdWE0do&list=PLvOG5uIz5zbr7B1ARPAxCz6K4a2erNiAY) where he discusses the character controller implementation.

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT:** Theory proved wrong, there is indeed little difference. Old answer follows, please see accepted answer.

Super Meat Boy is harder to play with a keyboard.

Gamepads can detect how much you are pushing the control stick in a direction; there are partial actions. Jumping to the right with 30% of run speed is possible to do.

Keyboards only detect whether you're pressing a key or not; you are either performing an action or not. So if you want to jump to the right with 30% of run speed you have to tap the right key at a certain frequency to simulate what the gamepad would otherwise do for you. This is especially difficult with a less than perfectly responsive keyboard.

Buying a gamepad is worth it depending on your experience with PC platformers. The gamepad and keyboard have different mindsets, and having already played through a good chunk of Super Meat Boy with the keyboard you'll have to spend time switching to the gamepad mindset. If you're a long-time player of PC platformers this will prove a painful transition. If you're not, then getting a feel for the gamepad will happen after replaying a few levels and you'll find the game much easier.

Comment: It's a similar argument to racing games are harder with a keyboard. A gamepad can turn you slightly right. A keyboard can only turn completely right or go straight, so you have to tap the right key at a certain frequency to get the amount of turning that you need. If you're a TrackMania player this isn't a problem, but if you're new to racing on the PC it's very difficult to learn.

Comment: So SMB does actually make use of stick angle and position?

Comment: *(I'm a keyboard gamer.  Only.)*  To compensate for the whole "On or Off; no middle state" dilemma, I find myself rapidly pressed and releasing certain keys until the power/speed/etc is *just* right.

Comment: @fail badp - It was coded for xbox, and both xbox and gamepads store the stick as a vector indicting where it is being pushed. I'm 99% sure that the answer is yes. If someone has an xbox or gamepad they could figure it out pretty easily.

Comment: @badp Sadly not. (Sorry, I had to). I've tried it with my gamepad, and it's definitely the same speed no matter how you push. However, SMB is, subjectively, a LOT easier to play with a gamepad.

Comment: According to @Arda Xi comment, SMB does not take into account the analog stick. Considering this is true, then this accepted answer is incorrect!

Comment: @DenilsonSá I don't see any factual errors. Can you cite them?

Comment: "Jumping to the right with 30% of run speed is possible to do": no, it's not possible. I've just tested it and had the exact same results as Arda Xi: the analog controls (left thumbstick an right trigger) work as digital controls, exactly the same as keyboard keys or gamepad buttons. Thus, the reason given in this answer is invalid for SMB (although valid for other games).

Comment: so super meat boy precision is in timing

Comment: Your answer doesn't mention Xbox 360 pad's pressure-sensitive triggers, the right trigger controls run speed in the game.

Answer (score -1):

I find it harder with a Gamepad.. I've played the entire game with the keyboard 
100% light world 
87% Dark world
i Use my little finger on the shift key and my thumb on the space key and i have my hand like i would if i was playing any game on the (WASD).
Somehow i feel i can control Meatboy better if i use the keyboard

Answer (score -1):

I have completed 106% of the game and died only 537 times with keyboard, for me its easier this way. U just need to practice a bit, only problem is that my left hand got paralized for 5 hours =/